# Частота обновления снимка базы данных

Tags: поддержка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, текущую частоту создания снимка БД rus.

Comment: предполагаю, что каждое воскресенье

Answer (score 3):

Снимок обновляется каждое воскресенье, примерно в 3:00 UTC.

Частота обновления и дата последнего обновления указана в FAQ:, https://data.stackexchange.com/help